supervisingroutecontroller isn't supervising all routes
Using Camel 4.4.1 and SpringBoot 3.2.3.
I have a very simple camel routebuilder:
import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;

public class SimpleTestRouteBuilder extends RouteBuilder 
{
    public SimpleTestRouteBuilder(int i)
    {
        // do something with i...
    }
    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception 
    {

    //  from("direct:messageReceiver").id("testReceipt")
     //   .log("received");
        
        from("timer:/foo?repeatCount=1") // read from the specified queue
        .routeId("fromrequestto0")
        .to("smpp://localhost:2775");
        
        from("timer:/foo2?repeatCount=1") // read from the specified queue
        .routeId("fromresponseto1")
        .to("smpp://localhost:2776");       
    }
}

Application.java is as follows:
@ConfigurationPropertiesScan
public class Application 
{    
    @Autowired private CamelContext context;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    CommandLineRunner init(ProducerTemplate template) 
    {
        return args -> 
        {
            Integer i = args.length == 0 ? 1 : Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
            try
            {
                context.addRoutes(new SimpleTestRouteBuilder(i));
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                // swallow
            }
        };
    }
}


Configuration - application.yaml:
camel:
  routecontroller:
    enabled: true
    backoffDelay: 5000
    backoffMaxAttempts: 17280
    initialDelay: 1000
    threadPoolSize: 2
    unhealthyOnExhausted: false
    unhealthyOnRestarting: false
    includeRoutes: "*"

On application startup, If the first route fromrequestto0 won't start because the sms-c is down, the supervisingroutecontroller doesn't seem to kick in, and the camel application shuts down. (this is because the warmup that Camel does tries to connect the producer- the smsc connection - and fails when this can't start)
If the first route does start up, but the second doesn't; then the application stays up and the supervisingroutecontroller kicks in, retrying the route until the second SMS-C becomes available. (this is what I want to happen in both cases, but it's weird because I would have thought the camel warmup would have failed here too?)
Why is there a difference in behaviour depending on the route here?

I found that using the CommandLineRunner to instantiate the routebuilder and add it to the context was what was causing the issue. When I removed the CommandLineRunner and just left it to camel to do it all itself, then it worked.
New RouteBuilder, for reference:
@Component
public class SimpleTestRouteBuilder extends RouteBuilder 
{
    // move i to here, read from the config file, instead.
    @Value("${camel.i}")
    private int i;

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception 
    {

    //  from("direct:messageReceiver").id("testReceipt")
     //   .log("received");
        
        from("timer:/foo?repeatCount=1") // read from the specified queue
        .routeId("fromrequestto0")
        .to("smpp://localhost:2775");
        
        from("timer:/foo2?repeatCount=1") // read from the specified queue
        .routeId("fromresponseto1")
        .to("smpp://localhost:2776");       
    }
}

See also https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-21319
I would be interested to understand why the other approach didn't work, or whether there is some error handling that I could do to make it work, however.
